# Show the project folder in the Aptana's "App Explorer" to SVN update or commit my project

Tags: svn, aptana

Aptana's App Explorer shows all files within a project. But for me to SVN update or commit my whole project I need to be able to right click on the project folder instead of only the sub folders. But the project folder is not shown within the App Explorer.

What I do now is switch to the Project Explorer and right click on the project folder there, but it would be much easier to be able to do that within the App Explorer. Does anyone know how to show the project folder in the App Explorer or a different way to update or commit my whole project within the App Explorer?

Comment: Can't you just do a Ctrl + A (select all) in the App Explorer then right click > commit/upload or use the briefcase/gears icon to update/commit?

Comment: Good suggestion, but CTRL + A also selects all the non versioned files, which disables the option to update. Commit seems to be posible with CTRL + A.

I do not understand which briefcase/gears icon you mean. Those are not in my App Explorer?

Comment: The briefcase is the deploy option and the gears is for git (thought it was general version control but I guess not?) My only other suggestion is to use the parent folder of your project folder, instead of the project folder itself, which would make the project folder you want to click on visible in the App Explorer (if that makes sense...)

Comment: This would mean that my projects should be build on the parent folder of my actual projects, which would make one HUGE project, which would then make searching and indexing very slow...